# Redux action `deleteTodo` does not work in todo-list application

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux

The code in `todoSlice.js` is as follows

```js
reducers: {
  deleteTodo(state, action) {
    const {id} = action.payload;
    state = state.filter(function(ele){
      return ele.id !== id; 
    });
  }
}
```

And the `deleteTodo` action is dispatched by the Delete button in `Todo.js`:

```html
<button
  className={styles.button}
  onClick={() => {
      dispatch(deleteTodo( { id: todo.id } ))
    }
  }
>
  Delete
</button>
```

When I click on the Delete button of a todo, the todo does not disappear.

Comment: try `const { id } = action;`

Comment: You might have to return the state in delteToDo reducer